# How to do multiple animation on a key press

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need you guys to help with my program, I manage to program it when I press a key and its moves. But when I press the keypad "1", my robot teleported to my first location after that move to my next location. But what I needed is, when pressing the keypad "1", the robot to move to the first location then move to the second location. 
Please help me as I'm new to HTML, CSS, and java. 
The bottom is my coding for the function.

```
                           <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
          <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
            <title>Document</title>
            <style>
              body {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                background-image: url("TPHRG floorplan1.png");
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-attachment: fixed;
                /* background-position: center; */
                background-size: 980px 400px, cover;
              }

              .robot_start_top {
                top: 280px;
                transition: top 2s;
              }

              .robot_start_left {
                position: fixed;
                left: 600px;
                transition: all 2s;
              }

              .robot_end_left {
                left: 570px;
              }

              .robot_end_top {
                top: 180px;
              }

              .robot1_start_left {
                position: fixed;
                left: 570px;
                transition: left 4s;
              }

              .robot1_end_left {
                left: 520px;
              }

              .robot2_start_left {
                position: fixed;
                left: 520px;
                transition: left 4s;
              }

              .robot2_end_left {
                left: 470px;
              }
              .robot3_start_left {
                position: fixed;
                left: 470px;
                transition: left 4s;
              }

              .robot3_end_left {
                left: 420px;
              }

              .robot3_start_right {
                position: fixed;
                left: 470px;
                transition: left 4s;
              }
              .robot3_start_down {
                position: fixed;
                left: 180px;
                transition: left 4s;
              }

              .robot3_end_down {
                top: 280px;
              }

              .robot3_end_right {
                left: 570px;
              }
            </style>
          </head>
          <body onkeydown="move(event)">
            <div class="robot_start_left robot_start_top" id="app">
              <img id="robot" style= width:30px; height:40px" src="pic_8.PNG">
            </div>

            <script>
              var move = function(event) {
                if (event.keyCode === 97) {
                  const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
                  setTimeout(function() {
                    appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_top");
                  }, 0);
                  setTimeout(function() {
                    appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_left");
                  }, 2000);
                }

                if (event.keyCode === 98) {
                  const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
                  appDiv.classList.add("robot1_end_left");
                }

                if (event.keyCode === 99) {
                  const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
                  appDiv.classList.add("robot2_end_left");
                }

                if (event.keyCode === 100) {
                  const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
                  appDiv.classList.add("robot3_end_left");
                }

                  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                    const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
                    setTimeout(function() {
                      appDiv.classList.add("robot3_end_down");
                    }, 2000);
                    setTimeout(function() {
                      appDiv.classList.add("robot3_end_right");
                    }, 0);
                  }

              }
            </script>
          </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Your comment abit redundant, could u try to reformulate with an example?

Comment: Can you show some example ?

Comment: I have edited my code. The above is my code. What I need is, When I press number 1, the robot will move from start to the first location then move to the next location. But currently I my robot teleport to the first point then move to the next location.

Comment: Your first setTimeout is pointless as the interval is 0, just call the appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_top"); outside of the timer function...it will be the same,. So what you are doing is adding "robot_end_top" immediately then 2 seconds later adding "robot_end_left"...is that your intention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you want to move your image to the top and left at once and your `left` argument is not working here, because you don't move it to the only left in the first click. To do the right way you must replace the `left` to `all` in `robot_start_left` like this:

```
.robot_start_left {
    position: fixed;
    left: 600px;
    transition: all 1s;
}
```

Here is the working option in **[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/html-css-v2f46?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)**.

Or you can add `setTimeout` to the event listener. That will give you asynchronous effect, like this:

```
if (event.keyCode === 97) {
 const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
 setTimeout(function() {
   appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_top");
 }, 0);
 setTimeout(function() {
   appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_left");
 }, 500);
}
```

For more info read this **[Article](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/transitions-and-transforms)**.

Good Luck!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, I try your way before, but what I wanted is, when I press number 1, it more upward then to the left. Hope you could help me with it. Thanks

Comment: So you want top go up and then go left instead of go left and up at the same time?

Comment: Yes that right. Hope you are able to help me.. thanks

Comment: Okay, stay here. I will try something now.

Comment: @ChiongWilson that was a very interesting bug, I even created my own question for that))) I hope it will help you. Wish you luck with your game!

Comment: Wa, believe this is a tricky coding.. hopefully someone would help us out with this. Anyway thank you so much. Appreciate it.

Comment: @ChiongWilson I find the solution, look at the answer, I made an edit yesterday :D

Comment: Totally appreciate your help. You save me a lot of time troubleshooting the program. Thanks and cheers

Comment: You're welcome, I glad that it helps, if my answer covered all gaps, can you accept it? Thank you))

Comment: In fact, I have another question, I notice the function is only able to do it once, it not able to execute multiple times. for example, sending my robot to the second location then back to my start point then move it back to the third location. Maybe you could help me? Sorry for the trouble. I have edited my coding at the top

Comment: Oh, it seems too complicated, I tried to find how to do it properly but didn't find it. Maybe you need to create a new question about that. I just find a good tutorial, I hope it can help you somehow here it is https://javascript.info/keyboard-events

Comment: I also find out that you want to write an event listener for the body, you just need to to add event listener to the document, that is a more proper way, here it is - https://codesandbox.io/s/html-css-q6524?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Totally appreciate your help. Cheers :D